# Is there "pwntools" equivalent gem for Ruby?

Tags: ruby, sockets, rubygems

or is there anyway to get this function working in ruby socket programming:

```
conn = pwn.remote('localhost', 4567)
conn.recvuntil("> ")
```

With native Ruby socket module, **socket.read(bytes)** will wait until it receives exact number of bytes, which i cannot decide apriori. And, **socket.recv(bytes)**, will print as soon as it gets some data, regardless of message being complete.

Since, I do know the message format and its ending, it would be easy, if there was a gem as mentioned above or any way to get the functionality in Ruby.

For eg, if i know the message from the server ends with colon,

```
socket = Socket.new( AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0 )
sockaddr = Socket.pack_sockaddr_in(port, hostname)
socket.connect( sockaddr )
socket.recvuntil ": "
# do something
socket.send "y"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
require 'socket'

def read_until(socket, re)
  accu = ''
  re = Regexp.escape(re) if String === re
  re = /#{re}\Z/
  socket.each_char do |c|
    accu << c
    return accu if re === accu
  end
  return accu
end

socket = Socket.new(Socket::AF_INET, Socket::SOCK_STREAM, 0 )
sockaddr = Socket.pack_sockaddr_in(80, 'www.google.com')
socket.connect(sockaddr)
socket.write "GET / HTTP/1.0\n\n"
headers = read_until(socket, /\r\n\r\n/)
body = socket.read
puts "HEADERS:\n#{headers}BODY:\n#{body}"
```